# Hypervisor is not running?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, powershell-2.0

I have a two part question:

- first is that can anyone please tell me the command lines to execute in docker to start building a container and vm?
- second is i have already built a VM using docker but the problem is whenever the building of VM reaches the stage where it written `WAITING FOR VM TO BOOT` it's stuck there and the error of `HYPERVISOR IS NOT RUNNING` comes even when the `HYPER-V MACHINE MANAGEMENT` is on automatic and running.
  So please, help me get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

To create a VM which will run docker, use [`docker-machine`](https://github.com/docker/machine/): copy [`docker-machine-Windows-x86_64.exe`](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.6.0-rc3/docker-machine-Windows-x86_64.exe) as `docker-machine.exe` anywhere you want.

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox
docker-machine start
```

But Make sure you have removed the Windows feature HyperV, as it is not compatible with VirtualBox/VMWare.
Or use the [Hyper-V driver](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/). You have to chose one or the other.

See "[Getting Docker running on Windows 10](http://www.westerndevs.com/getting-docker-running-on-windows-10/)"

> as it turns out, HyperV and VirtualBox will not run together side-by-side in 64 bit modes. And [Scott's blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/switcheasilybetweenvirtualboxandhypervwithabcdeditbootentryinwindows81.aspx) about rebooting to a `hypervisorlaunchtype` off mode of Windows 8.1 worked flawlessly for Windows 10.
>   So I didn't have to un-install the HyperV feature, but as it turns out, I did have to disable HyperV